# How to use variable in awk substr

Tags: awk, substr

n=4;
echo "abcd" awk '{print substr($0,$n,1);}'

I want to get the substring by the usage of variable but I am not getting please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ n=4; echo "abcd" | awk -v n="$n" '{print substr($0,n,1);}'
d
```

Possibly, it is clearer to have two different variable names:

```
$ n=4; echo "abcd" | awk -v m="$n" '{print substr($0,m,1);}'
d
```

Here, `n` is a *shell* variable and `m` is an *awk* variable.  The `-v` option is used to assign the *awk* variable `m` to have the value of the *shell* variable `n`.